# How to use Navier-Stokes equation to model incompressible flow when pressure moves towards infinity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, navier-stokes

I have a container of inviscid, incompressible fluid with a piston at one end. It is completely closed, except the fact that I can move the piston(say $x_p$). From definition of *Bulk Modulus*-

$$
\mathcal{B}=-V\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}
$$

Since $\mathcal{B}=\infty$ for any incompressible fluid, so any displacement change to the piston will give rise to infinite pressure.

I am thinking how to model this rise in pressure using Navier-Stokes equation. Let me write the simplified equations-

$$
\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}=0 \\
\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}} + u \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}=-\frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}
$$

If I give some finite value of displacement to piston, how to show that $p \rightarrow\infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an incompressible fluid in such a situation, the pressure is indeterminate.  Any pressure can be applied to the fluid (with no motion), not just an infinite pressure.  The Euler equation just gives p = constant.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What if I apply some displacement, u to the piston, which will lead to some change in volume and hence infinite pressure should come.

Comment: Don't worry. I found my doubt. Velocity cannot be applied out of nowhere, because I have the continuity equation also. Thanks for the answer.